# Databases are join and retrieve to the PHP

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I want to retrieve `item` name from `item` table which is equal to item numver in `inventory` table while inventory other details are directly populated. But it doesn't run. How do I correct this?

```
<?php include '../../config/Database.php';
 $pdo = Database::connect();
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `tbl_inventory`';
 $sql2 = 'SELECT tbl_item.item_name FROM tbl_item,tbl_inventory 
          WHERE tbl_inventory.tbl_item_item_ID = tbl_item.item_ID';

    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['tbl_item_item_ID'] . '</td>';

        foreach ($pdo->query($sql2) as $row1) {
            echo '<td>' . $row1['item_name'] . '</td>';
        }

        echo '<td>' . $row['qty'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    Database::disconnect();
?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace line sql2 with my sql2:

```
$sql2 = 'SELECT tbl_item.item_name as item_name FROM tbl_item,tbl_inventory WHERE tbl_inventory.tbl_item_item_ID = tbl_item.item_ID';
```

Your have to modify $sql2 string, when your using select statement what ever you written that will become result array associative array name `tbl_item.item_name` but your trying to get `item_name`that will not present in the result array, so you will not get any result. Give alias name tbl_item.item_name to `item_name` using **as** keyword in mysql.